# VirtualBox: This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU

Tags: macos, 64-bit, virtualbox

Trying to run Ubuntu 64-bit on my mac (OS 10.6, Intel Core Duo).

Seems like 64-bit guest operating systems weren't supported for Mac for a while, is this still the case?

Comment: We need more information in order to answer your question definitively, as a minimum we would need to know the model of your system and out of preference your processor model.  As stated by shf301 below the Core Duo (e.g. http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=27238&processor=T2700&spec-codes=SL9JP,SL9K4) is a 32-bit processor while a Core **2** Duo (e.g. http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=35605) is a 64-bit capable processor.

Answer (score 3):

An Intel Core Duo is not a 64 bit chip so it can't run a 64 bit system.  It has nothing to do with running a Mac, it's your processor.